# Symfony 2.7, как настроить маршрут по умолчанию

Tags: symfony2, маршрутизация

Есть регистрация, разделенная на шаги

Маршрут такой:
/register/{step}

Как сделать правильней, что бы маршрут по умолчанию был 1 (к примеру, по переходу по урлу /register)

**Конфигурация (yml):**

```
register:
  resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/RegisterController.php"
  prefix: /register
  defaults: { step: "choose_sex" }
  type: annotation
```

**Часть кода с контроллера:**

```
   /**
     * Выбор пола
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     * @Route("/choose_sex", name="register_choose_sex")
     */
    public function chooseSexAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_POST)) {

        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Register:choose_sex.html.twig');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае надо дополнительно прописать еще один Route для действия по умолчанию.

```
/**
 * Выбор пола
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 * @Route("/choose_sex", name="register_choose_sex")
 * @Route("")
 */
public function chooseSexAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_POST)) {

    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Register:choose_sex.html.twig');
}
```

Обратие внимание, я добавить еще одну аннотацию с пустым Route.

*Не совсем ясно, зачем вы смешиваете конфигурацию маршрутов в YAML и в аннотациях. Но, это не имеет значения для ответа.*